# Searching with Elasticsearch for exact matching text

Tags: elasticsearch, exact-match

I want to search for the EXACT Area-of-work in the line below, right now it returns all records matching the area of work plus any others containing that word.

For example, if I search for *Finance*, it also returns me *Corporate Finance*. Can anyone suggest how to make this line to return the exact matches only?

```
boolQuery.should(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("audiences.areasOfWork", areaOfWork));


boolQuery.should(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("audiences.interests", interest));

BoolQueryBuilder filterQuery = boolQuery();
filterQuery.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("audiences.grades", grade));
filterQuery.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("status", status));
filterQuery.mustNot(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("audiences.type", "Valid"));

SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
    .withQuery(boolQuery)
    .withFilter(filterQuery)
    .withSort(SortBuilders.scoreSort().order(SortOrder.DESC))
    .withPageable(pageable)
    .build();

return operations.queryForPage(searchQuery, Course.class);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than searching in the analyzed field you would need to search in the not-analyzed field, optimized for exact matches.

You did not share the mapping of your index (an I'm also not sure which client you are using), I simply assume a default mapping for string fields.

What might help is the following changes:

- use match instead of match-phrase (phrase does not make sense for exact matches)
- use the field of type keyword (not-analyzed version of the text)

Bear in mind, that with the above changes you need to match the exact string as it got indexed (same capitalization, same spacing, etc.)

```
boolQuery.should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("audiences.areasOfWork.keyword", areaOfWork));
```

Comment: Thank you for you quick reply! I've added 'keyword' as you suggested and I'm getting some more results back, I need to analyse the results and I'll get back to you, once again I really appreciate your prompt suggestion!

Comment: That returned based on exact keyword so thank you for your answer! Do you know of any good links for building these types of Jest Java Spring QueryBuilder ES? Something that contains info on 'keyword' field types etc?

Comment: You also no longer need to use the slight more expensive "Phrase"-query. Unfortunately I can't really help about your second question. You may want to create another question of SO for that.